# modifying a payload containing array of objects

Tags: node-red

Just trying to learn Node-Red, and struggling with handling messages.

I have a node that queries a mysql database and returns a payload containing an array of objects.
payload: [image]

I am wanting to pass the values to a dashboard graph node.
However I believe I need to pass it an array in the form

```
payload: array[64]
[0...9]
 [0: 22.2]
   .
   .
```

etc.

I've tried a function -

```
var outmsg = [];
for (var w in msg)
{
   outmsg.push(w.Temperature);
}
return {payload: outmsg, topic: msg.length};
```

Obviously this is completely the wrong way of doing it...
Can anyone help please?

ps.  Sorry if this is a duplicate of something answered somewhere else. I did google, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best practice to not recreate messages, but to pass on the input message if possible, so the following is better:

```
for (var i in msg.payload) {
    msg.payload[i] = msg.payload[i].time
}
return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after much messing around...

```
var inmsg = {payload: msg.payload};
var outmsg = [];
for (var w in inmsg.payload)
{
  outmsg.push(inmsg.payload[w].Temperature);
}
return {payload: outmsg, topic: inmsg.length};
```